# Simple error/rule check being ignored inside a while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to return a new number with each iteration, but these values have to be unique, it cannot add the same value twice.

I added an if check to see if the number is already in the array but for some reason it keeps getting ignored and adds duplicate numbers sometimes.

```
$data = array(0 => array('random_id' => '1'), 1 => array('random_id' => '2'), 2 => array('random_id' => '3'), 3 => array('random_id' => '4') );

$new_data = array();
$count = 0;

while(true){

  $rand = rand(1, 6);
  if(in_array($rand, array_column($data, 'random_id'))){
      continue;
  } else {
      $arr = $rand;
      array_push($new_data, $arr);
      $count++;
  }

  if($count == 3){
      break;
  }

}
```

Here is the problem: https://eval.in/957298

Comment: Why not simply *shuffle* the input and only take *n* elements from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking to see if the value is in `$new_data` before doing the push.

Make the previous conditional into:

```
if (in_array($rand, array_column($data, 'random_id')) || in_array($rand, $new_data)) {
```

Then, of course, you need to be aware that you're asking for three results when only two are available.

As far as generating a set of unique random numbers, here is an easier way to do that:

```
$data = [];
while (count($data) < 3) {
    $rand = rand(1,6);
    if (!in_array($rand, $data))
        $data[] = $rand;
}
```

This will fill `$data` with three random numbers in the range of 1 to 6

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because array returned from `array_column()` only have these values and you have provided range 1 to 6 in `rand()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

> Check here:
>   http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc1d4ea514199707e38821f6b395dd4153b0a32b